# javascript .click() method not work on android in some cases

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, web, webview

HTML CODE OF THE LINK :

```
<a href="#" id="10" target="_blank">
    some codes here...
</a>
```

THE CODE I CALL IN MY APPLICATION :

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('10').click();})()");
```

BUT NO RESULTS...

I've enabled javascript for my webView before and it works...
and Also I've tested .click() method for other elements on other web pages and it works correctly.

What should I do to make webView click on the link... ? Help me please; Thank you !

---

```
EDIT :

Perhaps it's because of the numeric start of id name of these elements,
    but I can use them using their id or tag name on
    google chrome console on windows without any problem...

but It's not possible to use them using their tag name, even, to click on, on android webView !
```

---

```
EDIT 2 :

The problem isn't numeric start of 'id's in fact !
I've found out that click function doesn't work even for other ids without numerics
    IN THIS PAGE I'M USING ONLY...
        AND THIS IS WHAT I CAN'T UNDERSTAND WHY !!!
I've tried creating fireEvent function, too... FAIL AGAIN !


I SHOULD ADD THAT THE HTML CODE OF THE PAGE IS SOMETHING LIKE THIS IN FACT :

    <div class="abc"><a href="#" id="defg"></a></div>
```

---

```
EDIT 3 : Sorry I forgot to say that these elements should open a window in the page
    when they are called by click.

I found out that when I click them using javascript on android,
    the html source of the page changes ( so the Click is being called as we need )
    , but the window doesn't open and it's data are not received...
```

---

```
EDIT 4 : I have used these codes after defining my webView, so what's the problem exactly ???

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(client);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(iface, "droid");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think ID and NAME must begin with letter. try changing id="10" to id="i-10", and also change in javascript call.

Comment: thank you, but isn't there any other way ?

because it's possible to use these elements on google chrome console on windows for example...

Comment: Also with html5 you can use `data-` inside elements to reference certain element.

Comment: could you please help me more... ?
how can i use this on android to click on this element in webview ?

Comment: Try creating function `doClick()`  in javascript width what it needs to do, make id to start with letter,and call
view.loadUrl("javascript:doClick()"); ?

Comment: thank you but I can't change the id of them... any other opinion ? :(

Comment: PLEASE READ EDIT 2 OF MY QUESTION... :(

Comment: Sorry, but I really couldn't understand your EDIT2 :/, Try finding someone to help you translate. But if id starting with number is a problem, try to reference the item in some other manner. For example, try to get the parent element and access to the child of element 
like so: `var elem = document.getElementById('parent_div');
var child = elem.children[0];` . Or just contact the website developer to add some deta- tags that you could call, or just add the class to every element that you must reference, but with PROPER naming (not starting with number).

Comment: thank you for your response and replies. :)

Sorry if my sentences wasn't understandable...


my problem is that I can't use click function on this web page even for non-numeric id's !!! I don't know why but '.click' function and other ways don't work with my webView (android) for this web page ! ( only this webPage... )

JavaScript is enable for webView in android application and my desktop browsers can click on those elements using java script console also... so what's the problem really ??? :/

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say that these elements should open a window in the page when they are called by click.

I found out that when I click them using javascript on android, the html source of the page changes ( so the Click is being called as we need ), but the window doesn't open and it's data are not received...